# Javascript Library for Markup Controlled Animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I am looking for Javascript libraries like the [Revolution Responsive jQuery Slider](http://www.orbis-ingenieria.com/code/documentation/documentation.html#!/documenter_cover).

If you are not familiar with this plugin you can specify animations in markup and the library will parse this and execute the animations on triggers or at page load.

For example:

```
<div class="caption sft big_white"  data-x="400" data-y="100" data-speed="700" data-start="1700" data-easing="easeOutBack">KICKSTART YOUR WEBSITE</div>
```

Are you aware of any similar javascript libraries that also feature animation attributes specified in markup and that integrate well with HTML5 videos?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.